# missing class "com.intellij.remoteServer.util.CloudBundle"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I am trying making a contribution of a outdated idea plugin
and then the code have missing symbols:

```
import com.intellij.remoteServer.util.CloudBundle;
                                     ^
```

```
public static final Icon MODULE = com.intellij.icons.AllIcons.Modules.ModulesNode; // 16x16
                                                                     ^
```

I am new to develop a idea plugin and I must missing something
the code is
**RestfulToolkitFeaturesProvider.java**

```
...
import com.intellij.remoteServer.util.CloudBundle;

import java.util.Collections;

public class RestfulToolkitFeaturesProvider extends ProductivityFeaturesProvider {
    public static final String CLOUDS_GROUP_ID = "clouds";
    public static final String UPLOAD_SSH_KEY_FEATURE_ID = "upload.ssh.key";

    @Override
    public FeatureDescriptor[] getFeatureDescriptors() {
        return new FeatureDescriptor[]{new FeatureDescriptor(UPLOAD_SSH_KEY_FEATURE_ID,
                CLOUDS_GROUP_ID,
                "UploadSshKey.html",
                CloudBundle.getText("upload.ssh.key.display.name"),
                0,
                0,
                Collections.<String>emptySet(),
                0,
                this)};
    }

    @Override
    public GroupDescriptor[] getGroupDescriptors() {
        return new GroupDescriptor[]{
                new GroupDescriptor(CLOUDS_GROUP_ID, CloudBundle.getText("group.display.name"))
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

gradle file is
**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.4.18'
}

group 'com.zhaow'
version '2.0.6'

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version '2020.1'
    localPath 'D:\\sft\\ideaIC-2020.1.win'
    plugins = ['java', 'Kotlin', 'yaml', 'properties']
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
dependencies {
    'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14'
    'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AllIcons.Modules.ModulesNode is deprecated in idea version 2020.1, use AllIcons.Nodes.ModuleGroup.